# Chrome-only Issue: Serving images using a servlet. One image loads, one image doesn't

Tags: google-chrome, servlets, struts2

**Edit**:

I have a page that contains the following HTML code:

```
<img src="/static/ads/1111.png"> <!-- 1 -->
<img src="/static/2222.png"> <!-- 2 -->
```

When I load the page, Image No. 1 cannot be displayed. Image No. 2 is displayed.

Checking the image request in Chrome DevTools's network tab, the request is always "pending".

What's even weirder, when I directly access Image No. 1 as in `http://localhost:8080/static/ads/1111.png`, the image actually loads.

This issue only seems to affect Google Chrome. I tested it in Firefox and it works there.

For Chrome I get a console error:

`Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

When I compare the request headers of Image No. 1

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8181/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31
```

vs Image No. 2

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8181
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8181/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31
```

There is a big difference. Anyone know what's going on?

---

**More Information**

I'm using BalusC's [FileServlet](http://balusc.blogspot.sg/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) to serve files found outside my web-app directory.

My web app uses Struts2 as its framework.

My web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.FileServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have excluded this path in struts.xml like so:

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/static/.*"/>
```

Comment: did you check in the image folder. whether the image has been uploaded or not?

Comment: Hi, yes. I have both images in the folder.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using some ad-blocking plugin which would filter out images fom ** /ads/ **?

Comment: Oh my god. You're correct. You are a lifesaver. Thanks. Can you place your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the right one? Ugh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From JB Nizet:

Are you sure you're not using some ad-blocking plugin which would filter out images fom ** /ads/ **?

Comment: OH MY GOD! I spent SO MUCH TIME today trying to find the issue. Thank you so much!